# How to mock docker ApiClient in Golang?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, go

I've implemented a wrapper for the [Docker ApiClient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#APIClient) like so

```
type DockerClient struct {
    cli client.APIClient
}
```

I've also defined my own interface for interacting with Docker like so

```
type Dockerer interface {
    Init() error
    CreateContainer(ctx context.Context, imageName string) (string, error)
    RunCommand(ctx context.Context, containerId string, command string) (string, int, error)
    StopContainer(ctx context.Context, containerId string) error
}
```

`DockerClient` implements the functions in the `Dockerer` interface like so:

```
func (d *DockerClient) Init() error {
    //...
}

func (d *DockerClient) CreateContainer(ctx context.Context, imageName string) (string, error) {
    //...
}


func (d *DockerClient) RunCommand(ctx context.Context, containerId string, command string) (string, int, error) {
    //...
}

func (d *DockerClient) StopContainer(ctx context.Context, containerId string) error {
    //...
}
```

This has made it easy to test the components of my code that need to interface with Docker because I can generate a mock for my `Dockerer` interface and dependency inject that mock.

However, now I'd like to write tests for the actual implementation of the `DockerClient` wrapper. It seems like no mocks are provided for `ApiClient` by the docker package. Is there a canonical pattern for writing tests when the package I need to use doesn't provide mocks? Is there a way to get [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery) to generate mocks for library interfaces?

Answer (score 4):

[client.APIClient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#APIClient) is an interface. You can embed that interface in a struct. Yes you can do this. ***You can embed interface inside struct.*** Then you selectively implement methods that you need for test. This way you don't have to implement every single method from the interface. It will impractical to implement all the methods that `client.APIClient` provides because it embeds interface that embeds whole lot of interfaces. [See](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#CommonAPIClient).

Like this,

```
type mockCli struct{
   client.APIClient
}

func (mockCli) ClientVersion() string {
   return "5"
}


func TestA(t *testing.T) {
   dc := &DockerClient{
      cli: new(mockCli),
   }

   ...

   dc.Init() 
   // This will print "5" if your Init has 
   // fmt.Println(d.cli.ClientVersion())) somewhere.

   // If you call any other method of cli, you get panic. 
   // A good thing. It will inform you that you are using 
   // some method that you don't have on mockCli. You 
   // just add it then. 
   
}
```

Comment: Ah, very cool. Is there a way to leverage this idea along with mockery so that I can make a mock implementation with all of the interfaces implemented?

Comment: No idea. I haven't used mockery.